# plot arrows in SF polygon

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

What is correct way to plot a curved arrow between centroid of polygons?

I tried the `curvedarrow` function from `diagram` package, but it's plotting arrows on some other places, probably due to different cordinates system.

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
plot(st_geometry(nc))
nc$centroid<- st_centroid(nc$geometry)
plot(nc$centroid, add=T, pch=3, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: curvedarrow works for me. What are you doing with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from your example. To simplify, just use the first four polygons:

```
> plot(st_geometry(nc)[1:4])
```

Get the four polygon centroids. Ignore the warning:

```
> xy = st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc)[1:4,])
Warning messages:
1: In st_centroid.sf(nc) :
  st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries of x
2: In st_centroid.sfc(st_geometry(x), of_largest_polygon = of_largest_polygon) :
  st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data
```

And draw some curved arrows between centroids:

```
> curvedarrow(from=xy[2,],to=xy[1,],lcol="red", curve=.2)
> curvedarrow(from=xy[4,],to=xy[1,],lcol="red", curve=.2)
```

that one's curved off the plot, so flatten it a bit:

```
> curvedarrow(from=xy[4,],to=xy[1,],lcol="red", curve=.12)
```

[image]

I've added all the centroids to this plot so you  can see it is drawing curves from centroid to centroid.

Comment: Sure it does plot Thanks for the answer. But if I try this using mapview it  plots some straight line. like exmaple  mapview(nc$geometry)+ mapview(nc$centroid)
 + mapview(curvedarrow(from=xy[2,],to=xy[1,],lcol="red", curve=.2))

Comment: That's a new question - make a reproducible example and create a new question - perhaps on gis.stackexchange.com instead of here as that's the place for GIS related questions.